# PyQt - QWidget - Show Title bar only

Tags: python, pyqt, qwidget

I am opening multiple files in my application. For big files it takes few seconds to open, Hence I am displaying a QWidget with status of opened files.

The Main application passes a signal to qwidget and titlebar gets updated.

I used `setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowTitleHint)` to get rid of minimize/maximize buttons.

1. Is it the right way to do it?

[image: Screenshot showing the window title]

2. Is it possible for QWidget to show title bar only?

[image: Screenshot showing the window title without buttons]

```
#This is the method for reading files in the main class
#Some other method passes filenames to this method
def readfiles(self,filenames):
    fopenstins=FileOpenStatusWidget()
    fopenstins.show()
    for i in range(len(filenames)): # Read files one by one
        self.emit(SIGNAL('fopenstsig'),i+1,len(filenames)) 
        #### More Code for reading files#####

class FileOpenStatusWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(FileOpenStatusWidget, self).__init__()
        self.connect(main,SIGNAL('fopenstsig'),self.qwrtt)
        self.layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.status=QtGui.QLabel()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.status) # This does not work -- Window remains blank 
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowTitleHint)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)


     def qwrtt(self,openedfiles,totalfiles):
         self.status.setText('Opening File '+str(openedfiles)+'/'+str(totalfiles))
         if openedfiles==totalfiles:
            self.hide()
         else:
            self.setWindowTitle(self.status.text())
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Can you show a code snippet?

Comment: Updated with code snippet...(Scared)

Comment: My initial idea was to add a Progress bar but the window remains blank even after adding widgets to it. Only thing working was Title bar.

Comment: Is this question about having a window which only consists of its title bar or is it about adding a label to a QWidget? I think your code above should work and the only reason your Window remains blank is that the label has no text in it, which one would see.

Comment: Just a question: Is the inverse, i.e. having a window without titlebar and frameborder an option for you? This could be achieved using `setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)`.

Comment: I wanted to add a label+progressbar with the status, but the window remains blank, I don't know why. Hence I'm using titlebar for displaying same info.

Comment: self.status is Qlabel. I'm extracting the text from self.status and adding to titlebar. So label has text in it (I think).

Comment: @inxp. The `for-loop` will block the gui. Use [QProgressDialog](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qprogressdialog.html).

Comment: @ekhumoro Exactly what I needed in the first place....Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of flags: `Qt.CustomizeWindowHint | Qt.WindowTitleHint`.

Window icon and close button are controlled by the `Qt.WindowSystemMenuHint`, which is added by default. `Qt.CustomizeWindowHint` disables all default hints.

Comment: Ok.. This got rid of exe icon and close button, but blank window below Titlebar still exists.